# Assign 'Y' flag if 'Y' is present in multi set table

Tags: sql

I am trying to get a sql for below data. 
I have data like

```
id   | flag
1    | Y
2    | Y
1    | Y
2    | N
1    | Y
1    | Y
1    | Y
3    | N
3    | N
3    | N
2    | N
3    | N
```

Expeted output

```
1 | Y
2 | Y
3 | N
```

if id column has Y and or N then display Y. if it contains Only N then Display N

Comment: Did you write any query for this?

Comment: Yes I did. select id , max( case when flag = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end ) flag_value from table_name group by 1   and then I simply swapped 1 with Y and  0 with N

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to group and count the values for the group. You said *if it contains Only N then Display N*. This means when all the flags that contain `N` equal all the elements in the group then you should display an `N`. Otherwise, a `Y`.

So you just need to group by and perform the previous comparison. Literally. This will allow you to respond properly in case a `Z` or a `NULL` flag comes in the future.

**Standard SQL**

```
SELECT id,
  CASE WHEN SUM(flag = 'N') = COUNT(*) THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END groupedFlag
FROM tab GROUP BY id
```

**MySQL**

```
SELECT id, IF(SUM(flag = 'N') = COUNT(*), 'N', 'Y') groupedFlag
FROM tab GROUP BY id
```

Fiddle with `Z` and `NULL` flags [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bc904/1).

Comment: Is there an error in Standard SQL written? . can we give like this SUM(flag = 'N')?

Comment: Nope. That results in a boolean expression which in MySQL becomes a 1 or a 0 and that can be applied a SUM function

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT [id], MAX([flag]) 
FROM Table1 GROUP BY [id]
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/567af/1)

Comment: If you don't clarify the fact that when flag = `Z` comes the query will no longer work this answer is not complete

Comment: Yup. You are right @MostyMostacho . But a general rule for flag column is to carry bools.

Answer (score 1):

This will work if you have values other than `Y` and `N` in the columns.

```
SELECT t1.id, IF(t2.id IS NULL,'N','Y') AS flag
FROM tab t1 LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT id FROM tab 
    WHERE flag = 'Y'
) t2 ON t1.id = t2.id GROUP BY t1.id
```

Otherwise, Praveen's answer is much simpler.

Comment: Note if the table contains `(4, NULL)` this will return `N` and it doesn't actually fulfills the condition *if it contains Only N then Display N*

Comment: If you wanted to stick to OPs requirements super exactly, you could add another subquery join as `t3`, but with `WHERE flag NOT IN ('Y', 'N')` and then add a `WHERE t3.id IS NULL` to the outer query.  This would exclude all rows that have flags other than `Y` or `N`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried below approach it worked fine. But I was not convinced with my own `query`

```
select id, max( case when flag = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end ) flag_value
from table_name group by 1
```

and then I simply swapped `1` with `Y` and  `0` with `N`

I was looking if I could improve this further.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
 select id,max(flag) as flag from test group by id
```